# Change product tabs name and position in magento

Tags: magento, tabs, position, rename, product

I have a product page on magento and the default product description tab i would like to be able to change the name to artist description.

(http://www.avenueart.co.uk/still-life-with-irises-vincent-van-gogh.html) Example page

Also I wan to change the order in which they appear.

How would I do this?

Thanks,

George

Answer (score 1):

1. You may change title of tab "Product description"

a) in your local.xml file

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
<action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
<action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Description (**YOUR TITLE**)</value></action>
</block>
```

b) or via /app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv (localization file)
(i use this method in one [project](http://natural-luks.com/))

added line **"Product Description","Artist Description"**

2. You may use tag "before" or "after" in your block. Here is an [official guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/controlling-block-order).

examle:

```
<block type="cms/block" before="some-other-block" name="left.permanent.callout">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also similar requirement, I have `Specifications and Description tabs` and I have to swap their positions on the product details page. 
Therefore in the `catalog.xml`, I have changed the below code

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Specifications</value></action>
                </block>
                <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Description</value></action>
                </block>
```

to

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Specifications</value></action>
                </block>
                <block type="catalog/product_view_description" after="product.attributes" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Description</value></action>
                </block>
```

Basically, I have added the after attribute in the block tag.

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2 change order of tabs on product page.

You can easily customise order of tab in simple way.

1. Create details.phtml file in

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/

If details.phtml file already exist so update it.

2. Add this code before foreach loop. Define "$detailedInfoGroup" array.

Original code:

```
<?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $block->getGroupChildNames('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
    <div class="product info detailed">
        <?php $layout = $block->getLayout(); ?>
        <div class="product data items" data-mage-init='{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}'>
            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name):?>
                <?php
                    $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                    if (!trim($html)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                    $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                ?>
                <div class="data item title"
                     aria-labeledby="tab-label-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $alias ?>-title"
                     data-role="collapsible" id="tab-label-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $alias ?>">
                    <a class="data switch"
                       tabindex="-1"
                       data-toggle="switch"
                       href="#<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $alias ?>"
                       id="tab-label-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $alias ?>-title">
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $label ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="data item content" id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $alias ?>" data-role="content">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $html ?>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

After add code:

```
<?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $block->getGroupChildNames('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
    <div class="product info detailed">
        <?php $layout = $block->getLayout(); ?>
        <div class="product data items" data-mage-init='{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}'>
            <?php $detailedInfoGroup = ["product.info.description", "product.attributes", "reviews.tab"]; ?>
            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name):?>
                <?php
                    $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                    if (!trim($html)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                    $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                ?>
                <div class="data item title"
                     aria-labeledby="tab-label-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $alias ?>-title"
                     data-role="collapsible" id="tab-label-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $alias ?>">
                    <a class="data switch"
                       tabindex="-1"
                       data-toggle="switch"
                       href="#<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $alias ?>"
                       id="tab-label-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $alias ?>-title">
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $label ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="data item content" id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $alias ?>" data-role="content">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $html ?>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And add & edit name custom tab in product page check this link

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/207042/magento-2-create-product-tab-that-displays-custom-attribute/270432#270432